# UFW on Ubuntu 16, strange behaviour

Tags: iptables, ufw

I am moving from ubuntu 14 to 16 and have been getting some odd behaviour with ufw.

```
ufw status
ufw allow 22
ufw enable
```

My connection gets lost. I am not seeing this behaviour in ufw on ubuntu 14. any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Can you post the result of this command: sudo ufw status

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this command?

```
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
```

Comment: Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
root@tor1-kingslanding:~# ufw allow 22
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
root@tor1-kingslanding:~# ufw allow 80
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
root@tor1-kingslanding:~# ufw allow 443
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
root@tor1-kingslanding:~# ufw enable
Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)? y
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
.... Then my session gets closed, unable to reconnect, 80 and 443 also appear blocked. yep, i've tried allow outgoing too.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the upgrading process. Is it possible for you to reset everything by purging ufw and install it again?

Comment: Thanks. I've tried apt-get purge too, and it seems to persist. I am guessing that something has changed in the way that ufw works in ubuntu 16. But have yet to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your help. I didn't find the answer exactly, but I believe the cause was that I had copied over some ufw rules from my old ubuntu 14 install, which are located in /lib/ufw. Seems the ufw on ubuntu 16 did not like this, even after I deleted them. Reinstalling solved the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear that! One reminder though: I've read from many sources that we should proceed with care when upgrading from one Ubuntu LTS version to another. It's best to wait until it's officially supported (for Xenial it's until July this year) or just make a clean install instead (which is what I did). And even with a clean installation, old config files in the separate home partition (if you have one) might cause trouble with new versions of software (like in your case).

Comment: Yes, you are completely correct. I know I am playing with fire. For sure it was best to just make the configs all over again. Currently it's stable and I'm enjoying my http2 php7.0 environment.